# ASP.NET MVC Routing Failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where I have activated WEB API 2 routing. When the application launches with the default url the default action is not being called. I am getting the following message:

> "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

This started occurring when I activated the [controller specific] routing feature via the 
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() operation.

If I do not include this call the default action does get called.

If I leave the call in - I can still access the actions by specifically including them in the URL -- like
XXX/Home/
XXX/Home/Index

I have incorporated routing in previous applications. This application is a take over for me, and I cannot identify why the default action is not being called.

Comment: Show us your controller/action code a copy/paste full error message, please.

Comment: Do you have a routing attribute on the route?  Something like `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: there is no error.

Comment: no verb attribute on the action function

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what is actually happening, but it appears the WEB API routing was getting in the way when interpreting the base url. I do not know why this is the case as the routing for WEB API is based on a different routing signature. But when the dynamic API routing was turned on this issue started to occur. I solved the issue with a work around where I applied a new route handler and applied it to an empty route definition that had to be registered before all other route configs.

This is not ideal, and I still have to figure out why the WEB API routes are getting in the way.